Using SQLAlchemy 2.0 to Apply a Primary and Foreign Key to a MySQL table
everyone. Long story, short. I'm reading some Excel files into a Pandas dataframe. I am then taking that dataframe, adding a schema, and reading it into MySQL.
I have been trying to figure out a way of adding a primary and foreign key to the tables in my database so that I can run SELECT statements. It seems like it should be easy, but nothing I look up seems to work. Here's an example of code that I've been trying:
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, MetaData, Table
import mysql.connector
from sqlalchemy.types import *
import sqlalchemy as sa

df = pd.read_excel(r"C:filepath" + "TV.xlsx")
df2 = pd.read_excel(r"C:filepath" + "DIB.xlsx")
df3 = pd.read_excel(r"C:filepath" + "Reference.xlsx")
    
df_schema = {
    "Item #": Integer, 
    "Short Description": String (255),
    "Model #": String (255),
    "Pack": String (255), 
    "Member Cost": String (255), 
    "Suggested Retail": String (255),
    "Available": Integer,
}

engine = create_engine("mysql://root:1234@localhost/HardwareDB")
df.to_sql('truevalue', con=engine, index=False, if_exists='replace', dtype=df_schema) 
df2.to_sql('doitbest', con=engine, index=False, if_exists='replace', dtype=df2_schema) 
df3.to_sql('reference', con=engine, index=False, if_exists='replace', dtype=df3_schema) 
    
with engine.connect() as conn:
    conn.execute("""
                 ALTER TABLE truevalue ADD CONSTRAINT fk_element
                 ADD FOREIGN KEY ('Item #') REFERENCES reference('TV SKU');
                 """)

I have everything working, but I just can't figure out a way of adding the primary and foreign keys. I've tried the above method but get the following error when I try to add the foreign key constraint: sqlalchemy.exc.ObjectNotExecutableError: Not an executable object
I have also tried using the MetaData() option, which doesn't seem to work for me at all even though I followed the documentation for SQLAlchemy 2.0 Core (not ORM) as best I could. (I'm not a coder by profession :) ) The following code won't change the Column datatypes nor does it add primary_key. Let alone a foreign key.
metadata = MetaData()
true_value = Table(
    "truevalue",
    metadata,
    Column("Item #", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("Short Description", String),
    Column("Model #", String),
    Column("Pack", String), 
    Column("Member Cost", String), 
    Column("Suggested Retail", String),
    Column("Available", Integer), 
)

I would greatly appreciate any thoughts or input :)

"Not an executable object" -> wrap the SQL with sqlalchemy.text(...)

… or use conn.exec_driver_sql() instead of conn.execute(). Also use with engine.begin() as conn: instead of with engine.connect() as conn:.

SQLA doesn't directly support altering existing tables, only creating or dropping them. You can use raw SQL to execute ALTER... commands, or a migration tools like Alembic if you need a more "engineered" solution.

I reviewed your issue and i believe it seems minor issue. In SQL queries, column names with spaces or special characters need to be enclosed in backticks (`) instead of single quotes ('). Here is the revised code, please try with it and hope it will help to solve your issue.
# Alter table to add foreign key constraint
with engine.connect() as conn:
        conn.execute("""
             ALTER TABLE truevalue ADD CONSTRAINT fk_element FOREIGN KEY (`Item #`) REFERENCES reference (`TV SKU`);
""")

